# Git confused by file encoding?

Tags: git, encoding, unicode

I have some sql query file that were created in MS SQL Server Management Studio that when it's opened in VIsual Studio Code, Git thinks everything changed because of what seems to be an encoding difference issue. In the screenshot below, the old file has special characters all over the place whereas the new file doesn't. When opened in SQL management studio, they all look normal.

What can I do to avoid this issue?

[image: VS Code Git change comparative view]

Comment: What program is in your screenshot, exactly? I'm 100% sure Git does not look like that, it being a command-line program...

Comment: I am guessing one is somehow big-endian utf-16, and the other is little-endian, and the files don't have a proper BOM.  Not really a **git** issue. Fix your programs to save in a consistent format.

Answer (score 4):

If I am not wrong, it appears that the editor is Visual Studio Code. Some months ago I was faced with the same problem. However, recently I locally created a new Git repository 'Git Init' in the directory of concern and this problem cropped up again.

The first action I suggest is to check that the file encoding corresponds with that in the repository. 
This can be seen in the bottom right corner of the taskbar:
        [image: Bottom Right Corner of VSCode Editor]

Pressing the highlighted field brings up the "Reopen with encoding" and the "Save with encoding" list menus at the top of the editor by the 'Show Commands'. 
Trial & error the 'Save with encoding' and cross check when viewing under the 'Source Control' (HotKey: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) to see if the normal font can be compared.

In my VSCode profile settings per default is set:

```
"files.encoding": "utf8"
```

and in the Git repository I have now set:

```
"git config gui.encoding utf-8"
```

for the local repository, of course you can also set this globally by entering:

```
"git config --global gui.encoding utf-8"
```

which probably makes more sense if you have a collection of repositories.

I have not quite isolated where the bug is at the moment, but my guess is that VSCode is trying to guess the format of files and the guessing bit is not spot on. This then has the effect of uploading a file with the incorrect encoding that VSCode last saves the file as. The net result is that the comparison is not working as it should.

Hope this helps you all,